# Modern CV: Change Title

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I use moderncv for my Resume and I want to change something in the title, but unfortunately I couldn't figure it out by myself.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   %Paket für deutsche Spracheinstellungen.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %Das Dokument soll UTF-8-Format nutzen (wegen deutschen Umlauten).
\usepackage[left=2.4cm, right=1.0cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}  %Seitenrand anpassen.
%\usepackage{fontawesome}  %Paket für schönere Symbole bei den persönlichen Daten.

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

%\moderncvicons{awesome}

%Die persönlichen Daten:
\firstname{Firstname Secondn.}
\familyname{Familiyname}
\title{Resume}
\address{Street 007}{Country}
\phone[Mobile]{00000000000}
\email{fXXXXXXX@xxxx}




\social[linkedin][www.linke]{name}
\social[github][www.lgith]{name}
\extrainfo{}
%Die Dateiendung wird weggelassen.

\photo[2,5cm]{xy}  

\quote{"A more diverse future begins with more opportunities."}


\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
```

Comment: This is a bug in `moderncv`, in my opinion. They change the fontsize for the name part, but forget to add a `\par` at the end, so the change in `\baselineskip` isn't effectuated. You can "repair" this by specifying `\familyname{Familiyname\endgraf}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to put the name in a `\parbox` with a line break. For this you can include the family name inside `\firstname{}` and leave `\familyname{}` empty.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[left=2.4cm, right=1.0cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}  %Seitenrand anpassen.

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

%Die persönlichen Daten:
\firstname{\parbox{\textwidth}{Firstname Secondn.\\Familyname}}
\familyname{}
\title{Resume}
\address{Street 007}{Country}
\phone[Mobile]{00000000000}
\email{fXXXXXXX@xxxx}

\social[linkedin][www.linke]{name}
\social[github][www.lgith]{name}
\extrainfo{}
%Die Dateiendung wird weggelassen.

\photo[2,5cm]{example-image}  

\quote{"A more diverse future begins with more opportunities."}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]